# Regex get entire word starting with @

Tags: javascript, regex

basically im trying to create a regex pattern that get every word that starts with an @
For example :

```
@Server1:IP:Name Just a few words more
```

the pattern should find "@Server1:IP:Name"
Ive created a regex pattern that worked so far :

```
/@\w+/
```

The problem is everything after a colon wont get matched anymore. If i use this regex i get this as a result for example :

```
@Server1
```

how do i make sure it will get the entire word starting with an @ and ignoring colons in it?

Comment: Maybe `@[:\w]+`.

Comment: Or `/@\w+(?::\w+)*/g`

Comment: what is your expected output  ?

Answer (score 0):

it is works fine try it:

```
@\w\S+
```

https://regex101.com/

**\w** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

matches any non-whitespace character

**+** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 @[\w\s:]+
```

- \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

If your string contains any (!@#$%^&*()_+.) you could add them too.

Answer (score 0):

try this `@\S+`

It gives you everything between "@" and the next space.

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

refer [this](https://regex101.com/r/5pxHqN/1)